# mouseOver on touch screen

Tags: javascript, events, cordova, touch

I want to make mouseOver or hover like command in Javascript. I want when you hold your finger on an element that element changes attribute(get darker) and when you drag your finger on another element it changes to it's original state but the element on which is my finger currently changes. If someone knows what I am talking about please help me.

Comment: I know the trick. mouseOver seems absurd when ocnsidering touch... but sometimes you need to detect when finger 'swipes' over an element. Right ? Check my answer below. That did the trick for me, easily, I just had to put a "v" before my events... cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Touch_events as you can tell touch events are still in development. But the latest browsers have started implementing them.

Comment: This is Gecko. I didn't say but I need webkit.

Comment: @user868426 I edited it to the page on touch events in general.  I'm not sure if webkit uses these functions yet or uses the prefix.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't find a CSS only solution, you can capture the `touchstart`, `touchmove` and `touchend` events on your document and processing the `touchemove` (on each firing) by checking the `x,y` against the ones you want to highlight and add/remove the highlight class appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

use vMouseEvents from JQuery. That's the working thing.

Answer (score 0):

Virtual mouse event by JQuery mobile is quite welldone.

**https://api.jquerymobile.com/vmouseover/**